# Show $\lim_n P(|X_n - a_n| > \epsilon) = 0$ given condition.

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

Suppose that $(X_n)$ is a sequence of random variables and $(a_n)$ is a sequence of real numbers.

Suppose that $$\forall \epsilon> 0: P(|X_n| > \epsilon) \to 0$$
and $$a_n \to 0$$

I'd like to conclude that

$$\forall \epsilon > 0: P(|X_n-a_n| > \epsilon) \to 0$$

How can I show this? I tried to estimate

$$P(|X_n-a_n| > \epsilon) \leq \dots$$

but got nothing fruitful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\varepsilon>0$. Since $|X_n-a_n|\leq |X_n|+|a_n|$, it is the case that the event $(|X_n-a_n|>\varepsilon)\subset (|X_n|>\varepsilon/2)\cup (|a_n|>\varepsilon/2)$ whence
$$
P(|X_n-a_n|>\varepsilon )\leq P(|X_n|>\varepsilon/2)+P(|a_n|>\varepsilon/2)\to 0
$$
as $n\to \infty$ since $P(|a_n|>\varepsilon/2)=0$ for $n$ sufficiently large.

Answer (score 1):

$$ \begin{aligned} \mathbb{P}(|X_n-a_n|>\varepsilon)&=\mathbb{P}(X_n-a_n>\varepsilon)+\mathbb{P}(a_n-X_n>\varepsilon) \\
&\leqslant\mathbb{P}\left(X_n>\frac{\varepsilon}{2}\right)+\mathbb{P}\left(-a_n>\frac{\varepsilon}{2}\right)+\mathbb{P}\left(a_n>\frac{\varepsilon}{2}\right)+\mathbb{P}\left(-X_n>\frac{\varepsilon}{2}\right) \\
&=\mathbb{P}\left(|X_n|>\frac{\varepsilon}{2}\right)+\mathbb{P}\left(|a_n|>\frac{\varepsilon}{2}\right)\underset{n\rightarrow +\infty}{\longrightarrow}0
\end{aligned} $$
where I used the fact that if $x+y>\varepsilon$ then $x>\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$ or $y>\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$.